# Close commenting after X comments have been posted

Tags: nodes, forms, comments

I would like to ask if anyone knows how I can set a limit to the number of comments that can be made on a node with Drupal 7.

Perhaps what I'm asking isn't the best solution for what I'm trying to achieve.
I have created a content type (Event); each event will have a guest list which people can sign up to on a first-come-first-served basis. I would like each event to have a limit (ranging from 10 - 100) to the number of people who can register for the guest list position.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [drupal rules module](https://drupal.org/project/rules) to set up a system to close your comments after X amount of comments. In combination with the [views bulk operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module, you could set up a rule for "new comment has been posted."

For the condition compare the number of results from a VBO created that counts the number of comments on the node the comment was posted to and compare it to the number of comments you want before closing. If there are 20 comments posted and the number you want to close at is 20 the rule will move on to the action.

The action would be a custom php snippet to set comments from read / write to read only. The snippet I was using for Drupal 6 was

```
$node->comment = '1'; 
return array("node" => $node);
```

so it may need to be modified slightly for 7.

With that all being said, if you are looking to set up an event registration setup where a certain number of people can sign up, you are actually looking for the [entity registration](https://drupal.org/project/registration) module.

From the drupal.org website

> Entity Registration does lots of things you are expecting from a
>   registration system (like allowing you to restrict the number of total
>   registrations for a given event), and other stuff you are crossing
>   your fingers and hoping for (like building in automated reminder
>   messages for your registrants).

Comment: Will try both your suggested methods as i'd like to familiarise myself with the rules module. Entity Registration looks like it's exactly what i'm needing though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://drupal.org/node/304616#comment-1004389

And this module is in dev, so use at your own risk: https://drupal.org/project/comment_limit